# Request with postman is working but with browser it doesn't work (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, api, express

I'm making and API with expressjs, when i make a request with postman it works and i get response,  but when i do it with navigator it doesn't work, even i have enabled cors

This is the request with postman

[image]

This is the request with browser

[image]

I added access origin to my code

[image]

And I added cors

[image]

I tried with other browsers but the problem still the same.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code. Copy the actual text to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, authorization");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PATCH, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the port you are using (6000)

[port 6000 is officialy reserved to TCP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkWAK.png)

Just change the port to an unreserved one and it will work (in my case I changed to 5000)

I'm not 100% sure about it, but the reason it works on postman and doesn't on browser it's problably because the browser actually expects the 6000 port to be exclusive to TCP, while postman doesn't.

[link with full list of reserved ports](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_portas_dos_protocolos_TCP_e_UDP)